# Hibernate criteria query not giving complete resultset

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm struggling to create a Hibernate criteria query to fetch all the data as follows I need a list of all appointments in a chamber but only one appointment comes in every chamber.

```
    public static List<Chamber> getChambersInfoOfDoctor(Long id) {
    print("Finding chambers of doctor: " + id);

    List<Chamber> chambers = new ArrayList<Chamber>();
    Session session = null;
    try
    {           
        session = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Criteria c = session
                .createCriteria(Chamber.class).add(Restrictions.eq("doctor.id", id));

        c.setFetchMode("appointments", FetchMode.DEFAULT)  
        .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)  
        .list();  
       chambers = c.list();

        for(Chamber chamber: chambers) {
            Hibernate.initialize(chamber.getAppointments());
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch (RuntimeException re) {
        if(session != null) session.getTransaction().rollback();
        re.printStackTrace();
        print("finding patient: " + re);
    } finally {
        return chambers;
    }
}
```

Following is Appointment.java

```
public class Appointment extends BaseBO {


...
private Doctor doctor;
private Patient patient;
private Chamber chamber;
private WorkingDay workingDay;
private Slot slot;
...
```

Hbm

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.hibernate.relationships.doctor">
<class name="Appointment" table="appointment" catalog="consult_doctor">


...
    <many-to-one name="doctor" class="Doctor" fetch="select">
        <column name="doctor_id" not-null="true"  />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="patient" class="Patient" fetch="select">
        <column name="patient_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="chamber" class="Chamber" fetch="select">
        <column name="chamber_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="slot" class="Slot" fetch="select">
        <column name="slot_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="workingDay" class="WorkingDay" fetch="select">
        <column name="working_day_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
```

Chamber.java

```
public class Chamber extends BaseBO {


...
private Doctor doctor;
private Set<WorkingDay> workingDays     = new HashSet<WorkingDay>(0);
private Set<Appointment> appointments   = new HashSet<Appointment>(0);
...
```

Hbm

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.hibernate.relationships.doctor">
<class name="Chamber" table="chamber" catalog="consult_doctor">

    <many-to-one name="doctor" class="Doctor" fetch="select">
        <column name="doctor_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <set name="appointments" table="appointment"
            inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="Appointment" />
    </set>
    <set name="workingDays" table="chamber_day"
        inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" >
        <key>
            <column name="chamber_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many entity-name="com.hibernate.relationships.doctor.WorkingDay">
            <column name="working_day_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many>
    </set>
</class>
```

Doctor.java

```
public class Doctor extends BaseBO {
...
private Set<Chamber> chambers = new HashSet<Chamber>(0);
private Set<Appointment> appointments = new HashSet<Appointment>(0);
...
```

Hbm

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.hibernate.relationships.doctor">
<class name="Doctor" table="doctor" catalog="consult_doctor">
    <set name="chambers" table="chamber"
            inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="doctor_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="Chamber" />
    </set>
    <set name="appointments" table="appointment" 
            inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="doctor_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="Appointment"  />
    </set>
</class>
```

Patient.java

```
public class Patient extends BaseBO {

private Set<Appointment> appointments = new HashSet<Appointment>(0);
...
```

Hbm

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.hibernate.relationships.doctor">
<class name="Patient" table="patient" catalog="consult_doctor">
    ...
    <set name="appointments" table="appointment"
            inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="patient_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="Appointment" />
    </set>
</class>
```

Slot.java

```
public class Slot extends BaseBO {

private Set<WorkingDay> workingDays = new HashSet<WorkingDay>(0);
private Set<Appointment> appointments = new HashSet<Appointment>(0);
```

Hbm

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.hibernate.relationships.doctor">
<class name="Slot" table="slot" catalog="consult_doctor">

    <set name="workingDays" table="day_slot"
        inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="none" >
        <key>
            <column name="slot_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many entity-name="com.hibernate.relationships.doctor.WorkingDay">
            <column name="working_day_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many>
    </set>
    <set name="appointments" table="appointment"
            inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="slot_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="Appointment" />
    </set>

</class>
```

WorkingDay.java

```
public class WorkingDay extends BaseBO {
private Set<Chamber> chambers = new HashSet<Chamber>(0);
private Set<Slot> slots = new HashSet<Slot>(0);
private Set<Appointment> appointments = new HashSet<Appointment>(0);
...
```

Hbm

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.hibernate.relationships.doctor">
<class name="WorkingDay" table="working_day" catalog="consult_doctor">
    <set name="chambers" table="chamber_day" cascade="none"
        inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" >
        <key>
            <column name="working_day_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many entity-name="com.hibernate.relationships.doctor.Chamber">
            <column name="chamber_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many>
    </set>
    <set name="slots" table="day_slot"
        inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="none" >
        <key>
            <column name="working_day_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many entity-name="com.hibernate.relationships.doctor.Slot">
            <column name="slot_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many>
    </set>
    <set name="appointments" table="appointment"
            inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="working_day_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="Appointment" />
    </set>

</class>
```

Comment: please ask question in brief.

Comment: @ Hadi Jeddizahed now please look

Comment: turn sql query loggin on. then isolate the query you are trying to fix and its parameters. then run the query in a db gui. that will help to find if the problem is with your data or the use of criteria api

Comment: any good reason to use very old style of mapping and transaction management?